# Using jsonPath property in json schema returns a random string instead of the value in the given path

Tags: javascript, json, mocking, jsonschema, faker

Continuing from my [previous unresolved issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940463/how-to-use-reference-field-values-generated-in-the-same-json-schema), I am using `json-schema-faker` and `json-server` and i am currently trying to reuse some data from my json schema.

I have found  the property: `jsonPath` from [this](https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/issues/11) page in Github which explains exactly what I am trying to do and what my problem is.

I am trying to test this property from my JavaScript application which generates these data and also from the [json-schema-faker site](https://json-schema-faker.js.org/) which is the library I use. Using this property using any of the above ways, returns a random string instead of the id I am referring to ( `"jsonPath": "$..properties.test.items.properties.id"`)

[image]

Validating using [this](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/#) site, causes no issues and the value I am trying to re-use is picked up correctly using the `jsonPath`.

Is there anything I should import in my JavaScript code/mock data generator or what I am trying to do is not supported perhaps by the json-schema version?

Some of the paths I have tried to use are:

`$..id
$..test.items.properties.id
$..test.id`

This is my json schema:

```
{
  "title": "teest",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "test"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "maxItems": 3,
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "id",
          "samples"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "1,",
              "2",
              "3"
            ]
          },
          "samples": {
            "type": "array",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "test2": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "jsonPath": "$..properties.test.items.properties.id"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help with this as I can't find anything online, and I really don't want to mock these data using hard-coded values.

Comment: I'm not sure what `jsonPath` does in the context of this library.  It's not a standard JSON Schema keyword. Have you tried raising an issue on the *json-schema-faker* GitHub repo?  You'll definitely get more people who are knowledgeable about that library there.

Comment: I guess I should re-open the github issue I have posted here or open a new one as you suggested. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already found the solution to your problem but in case anyone else wants to know the solution:

Remove the `type` before `jsonPath` so instead of having

```
...
"items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "test2": {
            "type": "string", // Remove this line
            "jsonPath": "$..properties.test.items.properties.id"
        }
    }
}
...
```

change your schema to

```
...
"items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "test2": {
            "jsonPath": "$..properties.test.items.properties.id"
        }
    }
}
...
```

The json schema faker library does not know the type of your object you're trying to reference. Therefore, if you provide a type the json schmea faker will always override your relative value with a randomly generated type which is specified.
I struggled with this as well because the documentation of the library is not provided (for the very most part) and not detailed enough unfortunately.